# Are iOS 14 widgets animated / distracting?

Tags: ios, animation, widgets

I'm concerned about updating to iOS 14 mainly because widgets have moved from their own screen onto the home screen. I get reminded of Windows 10 active tiles which just don't know when to stop moving.

I use widgets often in iOS 13, but I really don't want to be distracted by them because they're...

1. Animated
2. Not out of sight

Are they animated? As in: are they allowed to animate in perpetuity?

Is there a solution to #2 other than putting them on their own home screen page? If so, are they accessible from within apps as they are in iOS 13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using iOS 14 with widgets on the home screen, & I don't find them at all distracting.

Firstly, widgets are only on the home screen if you put them there. If you don't they're all on the screen to the left of the home screen as in iOS 13.

I have the Music, Photos, Calendar, & Weather widgets on my home screen, with all but Music as a stack. The closest to animation that I've seen is that sometimes the top widget of the stack changes as I wake my iPhone. Of course widgets do live update, so there would be a momentary animation when one updates. If those updates are frequent enough I imagine it could look like animation, but I can't imagine why a widget would be updating so much.

Comment: This is good news (for me). I was under the impression that the leftmost dedicated widget screen had disappeared.

Comment: Still there & still default location. You've just been given the option of having them on your home screen.